# How to mount virtual machine's LVM partition on KVM host?

Tags: linux, virtualization, lvm, kvm-virtualization

If I trying to do following on KVM host:

```
# kpartx -av /dev/VolGroup00/kvm101_img
add map kvm101_img1 : 0 208782 linear /dev/VolGroup00/kvm101_img 63
add map kvm101_img2 : 0 125612235 linear /dev/VolGroup00/kvm101_img 208845
# mount /dev/mapper/kvm101_img1 /mnt
```

then I'm getting /boot partition mounted.
But I'm getting an error if I then type following:

```
# mount /dev/mapper/kvm101_img2 /mnt
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

Here is a fdisk layout on guest machine:

```
# fdisk -l
Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/hda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/hda2              14        7832    62806117+  8e  Linux LVM
```

Is it possible to find a root partition on guest and mount it on host system?

Comment: I suppose your reference to kvm101_img2 is a typo. It should be _img1 instead, right?

Comment: _img1 mounts correctly with method above, but _img1 is a /boot partition, equivalent to /dev/hda1 on guest. Problem was that I couldn't mount _img2 containing /dev/hda2 Linux LVM. That partition layout is default for CentOS installer.

Comment: Oh OK, I was thrown out by the reference to KVM. There's nothing KVM specific about this question then, it's simply one LVM structure inside another.

Answer (score 15):

Seems that I finally figured out how to do things I needed.
Here is what I did:

```
# kpartx -av /dev/VolGroup00/kvm101_img
# vgscan
```

if VolGroup names identical in guest and host systems, then you have to rename guest VolGroup

```
# vgrename <uuid> VolGroupXX
```

uuid of VolGroups you can check in `vgdisplay`.
So, the trick is in activating guest VolGroup:

```
# lvscan
# vgchange -ay VolGroupXX
# lvscan
```

After that it's easily mounted:

```
# mount /dev/VolGroupXX/LogVol00 /mnt
```

Finally, the backward process is:

```
# umount /mnt
# vgchange -an VolGroupXX
# kpartx -dv /dev/VolGroup00/kvm101_img
# pvscan
```

The last command cleans the LVM cache and removes the physical volume created by kpartx from LVM.

Comment: You might have to edit the guest's fstab in order to use VolGroupXX instead of VolGroup00 then.

Answer (score 5):

I'm glad you figured it out for your situation.

In the more general case, the guest drive could be in a variety of formats such as qcow, qcow2, etc., so you wouldn't be able to work on them directly. In this case, you might use something like on the host:

```
# modprobe nbd
# kvm-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 file.qcow2
```

Then you could access /dev/nbd0 as the raw guest drive. To stop using this device you should run:

```
# nbd-client -d /dev/nbd0
```

If, on the other hand, the guest drive were in raw format, you would use losetup:

```
# losetup -f file.raw
```

This would find and use the first available loop device (e.g., /dev/loop0). To stop using it run:

```
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

After this you would be able to do the kpartx / vgscan / lvscan / mount procedure you describe in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it using guestfish - http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately I couldn't even install guestfish: I spent hours of googling and investigating - all useless, it's not works :( Maybe there is some another way to mount linux partition? I don't need all-in-one tool to mount everything, just LVM.

Comment: try to run `qemu-img info /path/to/image`. if what you get in the Type box is not "RAW" then there is no way an OS can mount this image as a partition, because it is formatted as a qemu-specific virtual disk. This is what guestfish deals with, it's not just a simple mounting tool

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier just to use `guestfish` from the [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) package which should work out all the annoying details for you instead of trying to do it manually